# Possible areas within an integer grid

Tags: combinatorics, area, integer-lattices, geometry

Given a 1x1 grid with 4 lattice points $[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]$ (equivalent to a $2 \times 2$ grid of vertices), there are 2 shapes and areas that can be formed: a triangle and a square. There are 4 ways to obtain a $1/2u^2$ area (all the ways to form a triangle), while only one can result in a $1u^2$ area (since only one square can exist in the grid).

Assuming that no vertex of any of the shapes is found outside a lattice point, is there a way to calculate all possible areas and the amount of ways in which they can be formed for an $n \times n$ grid?

Comment: The possible areas are $\frac12 u^2$ and all multiples of it up to $(n-1)^2\, u^2$

Comment: @Henry I think you mean $n^2u^2$, seing as in the example, $n = 1$. To (brievfly) explain his answer, every shape you can make can be subdivided into right-angled triangles with short legs parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes.

Comment: @Arthur: I would see the original example as $2 \times 2$ as it has $2^2= 4$ points.  But apart from that minor issue, I do not think we disagree.  Pick's theorem also shows areas are multiples of a half-square

Comment: @Henry It's a $1\times 1$ grid of squares, $2\times 2$ grid of vertices. It's a matter of taste, I suppose, but in this case, my taste is to stick with what's been established.

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit my post to add that it could be interpreted as a $2 \times 2$ grid of vertices.

Is there any way to know the amount of times each area appears in the grid though?